# Gigabit modem to switch gigabit uplink?

Tags: switch, nic

Times change, and we are adapting to now having gigabit internet service at a local charity. Since there is a gigabit uplink on the switch already in place (Netgear FSM726) I was wondering if the router (gigabit but few ports) could just be connected to the normally 10/100 switch on the gigabit uplink port?

No devices on that switch would be able to go faster than 100, but the aggregate could if the gigabit uplink was connected (through a firewall/router) to the modem.

Do I understand this correctly?

Presumably a device or another switch could be connected to the second uplink port on that same FSM726 switch.  Is that correct?

Comment: If I geit it right you are asking if you can connect one of the uplink port (gigabit) on your netgear swith to another swith (100 megabit). if so, then you can. Most network devices nowadays support 100/1000 speeds, which means if you connect two devices and they are set to auto negotiate the speed, each of them will advertise the speeds they support and connect to the higher the both support, in this particular case (100 megabit)

Comment: No, the proposed configuration is: modem > 4 port gigabit router > FSM726 on gigabit port.  Then most of the devices are off the FSM726, and will be at 10/100.

Comment: Why not replace the 10/100 switch with a gig switch? Lots of good quality gig managed switches in ebay such as netgear GS724t or HP Procurve). Seems a lot better that having a gig uplink that can't be used to it's potential by workstations - but you can connect to the uplink port with the current switch. You may need to set the port to trunk mode.

Comment: This is at a local charity where I volunteer. There is not a budget for new equipment.  I am just trying to get the best out of what we have on hand. I understand the switch is 20 years old, but the building may not last 5.  So I am trying to do what can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, your understanding is correct. Each device connected to one of the FSM726's 10/100 ports would be limited to 100Mbps. But in aggregate, the devices connected to that switch should be able to exceed 100Mbps of Internet access because the "uplink" port is a gigabit port.

Make sure the uplink port actually runs at gigabit speed. If not, the cable is probably the issue.

Comment: And am I able to daisy chain on the uplink ports, should I have the need?

Comment: You can do that. However, some switches don't really handle uplink-to-uplink traffic very well. You might not see gigabit traffic working between them, especially with small packets. But it will work okay.